# finding time taken for tank to get filled in differential calculus mixing problem

Tags: calculus, differential

A $200$ Gal tank is half full of distilled water.

A time $t=0$, a solution containing $0.5 ib/gal$ of concentrates enters the tank at the rate of $5 Gal/min$, and the well stirrec mixture is drawn with a route of $3Gal/min$.

A. At what time will the tank be full

B.  At the time the tank is full, how many pound of conc will the well stirred solution be conc.

Comment: What have you tried? At the very least, figuring out when the tank is full ought to be a simple task.

Comment: To be honest.... Ive got no idea how to solve it

Comment: You don't know how to figure out when the tank is full? I actually don't believe that. That's elementary school level maths, and not something that someone who is given exercises in differential equations should have any trouble with. Forget the concentrates for now. How much liquid is going in and out? How much more room is there in the tank? How long does it take to fill?

Comment: You might want to check out not opencourseware. The 2006 differential equations course covers this exact sort of question somewhere in the 5th to 9th videos.

Comment: If u can be kind enough to help solve it.... It's an assignment due for tomorrow